# Pass two variables using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my web page I want to pass two veriables to another page. I use this code for it

```
function getStData(key) {
  var gender=document.getElementById("gender").value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var res = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("std_table").innerHTML = res;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "../../lib/HOS_AddMain.php?key="+key+"&gender="+gender, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

In the body:

```
<body onload="getStData('')">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" checked="checked" onchange="getStData(document.getElementById('searchIn').value)" ="" value="male" /> Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"> Female
```

how can i implement it on radio button click and show the particular information?

Comment: You should use PHP... After you make your XML request, on the next webpage, you should use PHP to render what has been updated.  PHP sessions combined with MYSQL are great tools for this.

Comment: I guess if you REALLY want to use only javascript, you could use form submissions on each webpage, but this will make the back button and refresh button very glitchy at best.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Answer (score 1):

You can use as workaround the localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('variable1', 'value1');
localStorage.setItem('variable2', 'value2');
```

Then on second page you can retrieveyour variable and delete them but I recommand to use backend rendering like php or jsp (as you prefer)

Or maybe you should go to a fully client app like angular  :)